# Calculate the derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm asked to find the derivative of the following:

$$
\sqrt[4]{x} + \sqrt[3]{3x}
$$

I attempted to solve the problem and got the following result, but my book says I am wrong.

$$
\frac 14x^{-\frac 34} + x^{-\frac 23}
$$

When I checked I got the following as the correct answer. Why is it 3x and not x? What am I doing wrong here?
$$
\frac 14x^{-\frac 34} + 3x^{-\frac 23}
$$

Comment: I guess there's a typo. *Your* answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of the answers is correct.

$$f(x)=\sqrt[4]{x} + \sqrt[3]{3x}=x^{\frac14}+(3x)^{\frac13} = x^{\frac14} + 3^{\frac13} x^{\frac13}$$

$$f'(x) = 1/4 x^{-\frac34} + 1/3 \cdot 3^{\frac13} x^{-\frac23} = \frac14 x^{-\frac34} +  (3x)^{-\frac23}$$

If the textbook meant to parenthezise the $3x$, it would be correct.

In decent form:

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{4\sqrt[4]{x^3}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{9x^2}}$$

Comment: Actually the textbook answer is equal to your answer, and it is right.

Comment: @JamesPak As I added to my answer: If the textbook meant to parenthezise the $3x$, it would be correct.

Comment: ironically, you forgot the $3$ when putting it into decent form :P